# Navigation with OData properties

Tags: odata, sapui5

I want to use a table for navigation purposes. Therefore I use the following code (the table looks good, all datas are complete):

```
// Admin.view.xml View
<Table id="objectsTable" itemPress="onSelectionChange">

// Admin.controller.js Controller
    onSelectionChange: function(event) {

        // After call undefined
        var partnerId = event.getSource().getBindingContext().getProperty("BUSINESS_PARTNER_ID");

        // After call defined and correct
        var objectId = event.getSource().getBindingContext().getProperty("ID");
        var router = this.getOwnerComponent()
            .getRouter();

        router.navTo("adminDetails", {
            partner: partnerId,
            object: objectId
        });
```

After debugging I found out, that the value `objectId`is undefined (while ID is present). This causes the navigation to not work properly.
So I looked at the data source (oData), which looks as follows :

```
ID | BUSINESS_PARTNER_ID | ADDRESS | FILES (oData association/navigation) |
.... All records are available, including the BUSINESS_PARTNER_ID
```

Why is the variable `BUSINESS_PARTNER_ID`undefined while all the data from the records are displayed correctly? I can query it, except `BUSINESS_PARTNER_ID`. Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Comment: are you using a named model while binding the items to table ?

Comment: @RahulBhardwaj, no... at moment I use the standard/default model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Just" change my query to

```
event.getParameter("listItem").getBindingContext().getProperty("XYZ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do partnerId and objectId have values? If the values for these are there        then we need to check the routing and your manifest files. If partnerId and ObjectId are blank.
       If these fields are blank i can think of another fix. Instead of binding the event from table, i believe you must have a columnlistitem or objectlistitem under your table. You can assign the press event on that and move this code to that. 
       Basically i am triggering the event from list item instead of table.

Thanks and Regards,
Veera